# Debugging stack overflow crash in UITableViewCell _performAction: sender:

Tags: ios, uikit, stack-overflow, uiresponder

I have the following dump in Crashlytics that I'm not able to recreate at all. I don't know where in the App it occurs.

[image: Stack overflow]

This continues on for another 510 identical `[UITableViewCell _performAction:sender:] + 144` stack frames, which is Crashlytics upper limit. It very much looks like a stack overflow to me.

I'm stumped as to tracking down the cause of it though.

`UIResponder` has a mechanism to provide a handler for a received event: `targetForAction:withSender:`. I can imagine this could lead to an infinite recursion, but I'm not using this method in my code base.

This isn't a lot to go on, I realise!

I'm hoping someone who's seen something similar might be able to hypothesise some possible causes. I don't know which of this application's view controllers or dozens of cell classes is causing the crash so I can't paste that code in here.

Can you suggest what else might might lead to the stack overflow recursion seen above?

Also useful would be ideas about how I might determine the problematic piece of code. Could I perhaps swizzle `_performAction:sender` for UITableViewCell to log when this call is used? Then I could try the various areas in the App and see possible culprits?

Comment: Do you override some methods from `UITableViewCell` ? Also the code from `UITableViewDelegate` & `UITableViewDataSource` might help to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks @danypata, it's quite a large App. There are maybe a dozen different table view controllers, lots more cell classes (overriding lots of methods), and many implementations of those two protocols. The dump doesn't give any suggestion about which file it might be in, so I can't really just copy all the code here! :-) I'm hoping a reader might have seen something similar and be able to hypothesise a possible cause. It's a bit of a long shot!

Comment: Did you work it out? It happened to me too

Comment: No! Never did, and I think the crash is still there. Sorry.